# Using JavaScript to append a ViewComponent to a Div

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Is something like this possible? I have a ViewComponent and I'd like to use JS to call it and apply it to a DIV.

```
    <script>
        // Get the side menu
        var sideMenu = document.getElementById('SideMenu');
        // Create the ViewComponent
        var directMessages = this.document.createElement("<vc:direct-messages></vc:direct-messages>")
        // Append the ViewComponent to the side menu
        sideMenu.append(directMessages)
    </script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this

create div around component

```
<div id="myComponent">
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyComponent")
</div>
```

create action

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public IActionResult GetComponent() {
        return ViewComponent("MyComponent", <arguments...>);
    }
}
```

ajax

```
<script>
    $.get("/MyController/GetComponent", function(data) {
        $("#myComponent").html(data);
    });
</script>
```